# Working with a script to move files between folders in a FreeNAS NAS

Tags: bash, cron

I have the following files:
[SOURCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IrvA.png)

> /mnt/CASTLE/iocage/DUMP/FLEXGATE/Houkagou Teibou Nisshi/

with the files

Sample_1.mp4;

Sample_2.mkv;

Sample 3.mp4;

Sample 4.mkv;

Sample_5.txt;

and I am trying to get a script to use it in a CRON task to periodically move the files that get dumped in it to the destination folder

> mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkagou Teibou Nisshi/

I have tried this code:

```
    #!/bin/bash

SOURCE="/mnt/CASTLE/iocage/DUMP/FLEXGATE/Houkago Teibou Nisshi"
DESTINATION="/mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi"

FILES=`find "$SOURCE" -type f | grep '.mkv\|.mp4'`

for f in $FILES
do
  while lsof -Fp $f  &>/dev/null
  do
    sleep 5
  done
  mv "$f" "$DESTINATION"
done
```

and got the following ouput:

```
mv: rename /mnt/CASTLE/iocage/DUMP/FLEXGATE/Houkago to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/Houkago: No such file or directory
mv: rename Teibou to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/Teibou: No such file or directory
mv: rename Nisshi/Sample_2.mkv to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/Sample_2.mkv: No such file or directory
mv: rename /mnt/CASTLE/iocage/DUMP/FLEXGATE/Houkago to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/Houkago: No such file or directory
mv: rename Teibou to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/Teibou: No such file or directory
mv: rename Nisshi/Sample_1.mp4 to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/Sample_1.mp4: No such file or directory
mv: rename /mnt/CASTLE/iocage/DUMP/FLEXGATE/Houkago to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/Houkago: No such file or directory
mv: rename Teibou to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/Teibou: No such file or directory
mv: rename Nisshi/Sample to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/Sample: No such file or directory
mv: rename 3.mp4 to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/3.mp4: No such file or directory
mv: rename /mnt/CASTLE/iocage/DUMP/FLEXGATE/Houkago to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi
mv: rename Teibou to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/Teibou: No such file or directory
mv: rename Nisshi/Sample to /mnt/HDD01/HDD
mv: rename /mnt/CASTLE/iocage/DUMP/FLEXGATE/Houkago to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/Houkago: No such file or directory
mv: rename Teibou to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/Teibou: No such file or directory
mv: rename Nisshi/Sample to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/Sample: No such file or directory
mv: rename 4.mkv to /mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkago Teibou Nisshi/4.mkv: No such file or directory
```

I am fairly certain that the problem comes from the fact the files have spaces between them.

I have also tried

```
mv "/mnt/CASTLE/iocage/DUMP/FLEXGATE/Houkagou Teibou Nisshi/*.mkv" "mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkagou Teibou Nisshi/"
```

Still got a very similar output.

Also tried

```
cp "/mnt/CASTLE/iocage/DUMP/FLEXGATE/Houkagou Teibou Nisshi/*.mkv" "mnt/HDD01/HDD01/MEDIA/SERIES/Houkagou Teibou Nisshi/"
```

Same result.

Comment: `'*'` does not expand when enclosed in double-quotes. `mv "/mnt/CASTLE/iocage/DUMP/FLEXGATE/Houkagou Teibou Nisshi/"*.mkv` will work. You are making your life MUCH more difficult using directories with spaces -- but if you must... your use of `find` must change. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and specifically [**5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time)

Comment: Yeah I hate the directory structure but I have no control over it T-T. Also you recomendation about the *.mkv seems to work. Thank you

Comment: Sure, no problem. You can still use the wildcard with move, it just must no be within the double quotes. A path like `"/my/path/to/file*"` only looks for a file named `'*'`, where if you do `"/my/path/to/file"*` file-globbing will take place as you expect.